# Pymongo Replica Set NetworkTimeout

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-replica-set

According to [Pymongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/high_availability.html#connecting-to-a-replica-set), I can specify just one member in my replicaset and as long as one of my seeds is online, it can see the rest.

I'm currently specifying only 1 member in my replicaset where domain2 is my secondary not my primary and this works fine when all 3 members are up :

```
MongoClient('domain2', replicaset='foo')
```

However, if I take domain1 down, it results in a pymongo.errors.NetworkTimeoutError and fails to connect to the new primary.
What am I doing wrong?